# SQL Server Object Dependencies

Tags: sql-server-2008

Red Gate has some pretty good tools, but I don't think that their Dependency Tracker shows how Tables are effected by the stored procedures that touch them.

Is there any tool that can scan a database and determine what processes INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE records from the table as opposed to just touching\being dependent on them? Seems like this shuld exist by now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, dependency tracking still isn't perfect. The reason is that procedures can reference tables by dynamic SQL, dependencies can be broken if objects are dropped and re-created (I've written about [how dependencies can break here](https://sqlblog.org/2008/09/09/keeping-sysdepends-up-to-date-in-sql-server-2008)). The best "first sweep" I have come to rely on is:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME([object_id]) 
  FROM sys.sql_modules
  WHERE LOWER(definition) LIKE '%table_name%';
```

Again, this won't find objects that build statements using dynamic SQL, and it can produce false positives because `table_name` could be simplistic and part of other object or parameter names, or included only in comments or commented-out code.

You can also check for plans that reference a table using `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans` and related DMFs/DMVs but note that this won't find any plans that have rolled out of the cache.

Comment: I am  tempted to write a crude SQL parser in a db trigger that would fire whenever a stored proc changes and to interpret and log the results in a table. I would think that someone must've beat me to this. Granted that this would not take into account dynamic SQL, but we tend not to use it.

Comment: Parsing is hard. That sounds sarcastic but I'm quite serious. Dynamic SQL is a big problem but so is deferred name resolution. There are reasons nobody has beaten you to it, but all the best to you.

Comment: I agree that parsing is hard. That's why MS should do it: because they already are parsing the SQL. I agree about dynamic SQL, that probably demoralizes people from attempting the to deal with pre-compiled SQL. As for deferred name resolution. I don't know what you are talking about :-)

Comment: Do you mean you don't know what deferred name resolution is, or are you being sarcastic? Hard to tell with the smiley. You can create a stored procedure that references a table that doesn't (yet) exist. SQL Server gives you the benefit of the doubt that you will create it before you actually EXECUTE the stored procedure. As for whether MS should provide this? I'm not sure. I can think of at least a dozen features I'd rather they spend time working on.

Answer (score 2):

Using SQL Search, you can search for the column name and find all the stored procedures where it is used.

It's a Third Party tool and that is **[Red Gate SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/)**

**Features**

1. Find fragments of SQL text within stored procedures, functions, views
   and more
2. Quickly navigate to objects wherever they happen to be on a server
3. Find all references to an object

Hope this will help you.

Comment: does not do dynamic SQL